# I think this answer shouldn't have been deleted

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I have just had this answer in my review queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6595502

and wanted to edit it an add some code formatting but I couldn't because it has already been removed. I have almost failed the audit because I thought this post was a valid answer so to pass it I choose it's of low quality.

In my option I shows the code that causes the problem and with markings how to fix it. It lacks formatting but it's a valid answer not a question.

Comment: It was deleted by the OP.

Comment: If so then probably because of the comments he received and the downvotes.

Comment: His fault.. sometimes people comment wrong things.

Comment: It was in the "late answers" queue.

Comment: If you say that the OP removed it himself why was it in the audit queue at all if it wasn't removed by moderation?

Comment: @t3chb0t It is being used as an audit because it has a helpful VLQ flag on it, which is what sent it to the Low Quality Posts queue and got it deleted. Although, a Not An Answer flag would have been much more appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer has absolutely **nothing** to do with the question. He is including jQuery and Bootstrap in his answer, while the question is about including a RequireJS config.

It is correctly deleted as it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: I looked at the question and at the answer agian and I admit it does not really gives the right answer but it's also not a question like the two comments underneath suggest. I guess they'd seen the _I have the same problem_ part and automatically didn't read the rest. Is there even a correct flag for that because I think it's neither a VLQ nor a NAA...

Comment: The answer having nothing to do with the question definitely qualifies it as Not An Answer. I have no idea how he even stumbled upon the question because it's not relevant at all to the problem he was having.

Comment: The internet is a strange place ;-) you always stumble upon things that you didn't intend to find :-]